# How to find the position of a web element in relation to another web element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying work out how to find the location or position of a web element on a page,but in relation to another element. I was able to get the location of the element using:

```
         Point point = text.getLocation();
         int xcord = point.getX();
         System.out.println("Element's Position from left side Is "+xcord +" pixels.");
         int ycord = point.getY();
         System.out.println("Element's Position from top side Is "+ycord +" pixels.");
```

Of course, this tells me the location of the element, in pixels but what I really want is to find the location of the element in relation to another element - Is it above another element or below it?

This is a good example of what I am trying to achieve: let's take the 'Answer' input box on stackoverflow page. If you type in the box, the same texts are automatically displayed in an area under the box. So if my requirement is to verify that the texts automatically displayed are actually displayed BELOW the input area (and not above it), is this achievable? If yes, how?

I tried finding the relative location of the two elements with the location method above, but surprisingly, console displays the same location in pixels, for both, which cannot be right as one element is at the top and one is at the bottom.

[image: verifyLocation]

Comment: You posted the code to determine where the element is on the page, where is your code where you try to determine whether the 2nd element is above/below the first? What about your code isn't working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: @JeffC, it doesn't seem you read the question before commenting. If I knew how to find the relation of the two elements to each other, I won't post the question. Where I have worked up to is what I posted. I am trying to find a way to continue

Comment: I read the question just fine. SO is a place where YOU do the research and show code attempts and we help you find the issues that are blocking you. You haven't shown any attempt to figure out the relative position yourself. You are asking us to write the code for you which is not what SO is about. If you already know how to locate the two elements, why can't you find the relative position between the two? Try some code, post your attempts if they don't work along with any error messages or why it's not working.